# Deleting an element from a LinkList by a boolean method

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to make my own linkedlist class for a school project, and I'm having trouble with a function I'm supposed to implement.

```
    @Override
    public boolean remove(E elementToBeRemoved) {
        MyNode<E> indexNode = first;
        MyNode<E> prevNode = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < lSize; i++) {
            if (indexNode.data.equals(elementToBeRemoved)) {
                prevNode.next = indexNode.next;
                indexNode = null;
                return true;
            }
            prevNode = indexNode;
            indexNode = indexNode.next;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How this function is implemented now (to my understanding) is that when I reach the node containing the data I want removed from the list, it removes that node, and returns true indicating that a node has been removed. However this would also mean that I can't remove duplicate nodes in one go, and to remove all instances of elementToBeRemoved I have to use this remove-method multiple times. Is there way I can implement the function so it will remove all nodes in the list that contains elementToBeRemoved in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning true when you first encounter the element you want to remove, you should have a Boolean that you set to true whenever you find the element.

```
Boolean elementFound = false;
```

And then you update that if you find the element

In the end just return that Boolean. I also added an else statement because when you find a element you want to set the previousNode.next next to the currentNodex.next node, and then set the current index to the next node, but if you don't find a element you want to just set the previous node to the current node and the current node to the next node

```
@Override
public boolean remove(E elementToBeRemoved) {
    Boolean elementFound = false;
    MyNode<E> indexNode = first;
    MyNode<E> prevNode = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < lSize; i++) {
        if (indexNode.data.equals(elementToBeRemoved)) {
            prevNode.next = indexNode.next;
            indexNode = indexNode.next;
            elementFound = true;
        }
        else{
            prevNode = indexNode;
            indexNode = indexNode.next;
        }  
    }
    return elementFound;
}
```

You also need to make sure to decrement the lSize after each element you delete

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me because let's say I found a node that contains elementToBeRemoved. As I do that, I remove the node containing that element, indexNode, and set the prevNode's next to indexNode's next before removing indexNode. That's all part of the if-statement. 

the remaining statements wouldn't work now that I've removed indexNode. prevNode would then be null because indexNode is null, and indexNode would also be null because indexNode's next is now null.

Comment: @RazerMackham I edited the answer can you check if it is working now?

Comment: But in this new answer, at no point is any node deleted.

Comment: @RazerMackham It get's deleted automatically, you don't need to worry about that. Java has garbage collection. But if you want to be sure it is deleted you can copy the indexNode.next to a temporary Node object, delete the indexNode and then set the indexNode to the temporary Node you created.